# How to Add Array List to React Formik Yup Validation Scheme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

Inside the form, there are 3 names inputs that return with a for loop. Validations are not working.

The warning that the list is empty and that the fields are empty do not work either. When the Submit button is pressed, onSubmit works without validation and data comes with an alert.

```
    <Formik initialValues={{
        names: []
    }}
        validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
            names: Yup.array().of(Yup.string().min(2, "at least 2").required().required("list is empty"))
        })}
        onSubmit={(values) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values));
        }}
    >
        {({ errors, touched }) => (
            <Form>
                {(() => {
                    const arr = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                        arr.push(
                            <div key={`form${i}`}>
                                <Field name={`names[${i}]`} />
                                <ErrorMessage name={`names[${i}]`} />
                            </div>
                        );
                    }
                    return arr;
                })()}
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </Form>
        )}

    </Formik>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          names: []
        }}
        validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
          names: Yup.array()
            .of(Yup.string().min(2, "at least 2"))
            .min(3, "required field value")
        })}
        onSubmit={(values) => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values));
        }}
      >
        {({ errors, touched }) => {
          console.log(errors);
          return (
            <Form>
              {(() => {
                const arr = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                  arr.push(
                    <div key={`form${i}`}>
                      <Field name={`names[${i}]`} />
                      <ErrorMessage name={Array.isArray(`names`)?`names[${i}]`:`names`} />
                    </div>
                  );
                }
                return arr;
              })()}
              <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </Form>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I think try this it is works. For more validation apply on index level https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/528 it will help

Comment: Warnings give the same warning for all fields. When one input is empty, it gives the same warning even though the others are full.

Comment: so if names is not array then show error at the end of all fields